# Remove list items from users who are removed/deleted from the site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

We have a custom SharePoint application in which we manage user records and other info about employees in lists. We need a timer job to run through the entire records and remove the user records(list)from the SharePoint site for which a employee(user) is no longer available in the organization, .

Please guide me, how to achieve it.

Comment: Just to be sure; you want a TimerJob that goes through all the lists that contains information about the employee (user) and delete those entries?

Comment: yes, and delete those entries, whom are not present in the organization as of now.

Comment: and you know that when you do this, you loose the information about who edited which document, if the user is not present anymore?

Answer (score 0):

First off, read this article: [Create and Deploy Custom Timer Job Definition in SharePoint Programatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148222/remove-list-items-from-users-who-are-removed-deleted-from-the-site-collection)
It's a good beginners guid, taking you through the steps of creating a timerjob, what code goes where, and how to deploy the timerjob properly.

All the code for deleting stuff about the employee should go in the `Execute` method.

A good step-by-step approach would be as follows:

1. Get all the lists storing information about the employee.
2. Construct `CAML Query` to query for items about the employee for each list.
3. Delete the found items.

Since I don't know the setup of your lists or their linking, the following code are just examples which you should change and expand into fitting with your requirements.

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApp.ContentDatabases[targetInstanceId];
    SPWeb rootWeb = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb;
    string[] listNames = new string[] { "EmployeeList1", "EmployeeList2", "EmployeeList3" };
    List<SPList> infoLists = rootWeb.Lists.Cast<SPList>().Where(list => listNames.Any(ln => ln == list.Title)).ToList();

    // If no lists are found, stop. In case someone deletes the lists.
    if (infoLists.Count <= 0)
        return;

    // CAML Query: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx
    SPQuery employeeQuery = new SPQuery
    {
        Query = string.Format(
                    string.Concat("<Where>", 
                                      "<Eq>",
                                          "<FieldRef Type='Text' Name='FieldContainingEmployeeNameOrOtherIdentifier' />",
                                          "<Value>{0}</Value>",
                                      "</Eq>",
                                  "</Where>"),
                "John Doe")
    };

    // Loop through all lists and find items for employee.
    foreach (SPList list in infoLists)
    {
        SPListItemCollection employeeListItems = list.GetItems(employeeQuery);

        // Skip to next list if no info on the employee is found in the current list.
        if (employeeListItems == null || employeeListItems.Count <= 0)
            continue;

        // As long as there are items, keep deleting.
        while (employeeListItems.Count > 0)
        {
            employeeListItems[0].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```